# WPF MVVM cancel window closing

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM. I would like to minimize the window instead of closing it. In other words, I would like to cancel `Closing` event of window and minimize this window.

How should I do that MVVM way?

If it's relevant, at the end I will set `ShowInTaskbar` to `false` and use WinForms tray component.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The common misunderstanding with MVVM is that there can never, ever be code-behind in a view.  That is simply not true.

The goal of MVVM is to *minimize* the code in the code-behind, but for things that directly interact with the view itself (such as Windows events), **it is acceptable to put in some code-behind**.  The code-behind would handle the Cancel, and may do the minimize, or call a command in the ViewModel, or some other such thing.

Otherwise, you are going to have to come up with a convoluted system of handling the event in the ViewModel, which breaks the MVVM pattern by having the ViewModel have a reference to the View (instead of the other way around).

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thank you!

Comment: Remember the point of MVVM is to make the business logic that would end up in the code behind testable. If you can take in the view as a dependency using an interface, then you are not truly breaking this concept, really you are coming closer to an Active Presenter pattern, but this isn't bad either.

Answer (score 1):

Just override the Closing event and do this:

```
e.Cancel = true;
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```